# symfony 2 form choice checkbox list return none when all checkboxes are unchecked

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, symfony-2.3

I have a form with checkbox list created as choice in symfony 2.3

```
$fieldProp['choices'] = $values;
$fieldProp['expanded'] = true;
$fieldProp['multiple'] = true;
$fieldProp['empty_data'] = Null;
$builder->add($value2['attrId'], 'choice', $fieldProp);
```

If i unchecked all the check boxes and submitting the form the request not contain the field.
I am receiving the result as

```
$formValues = $request->request->get($form1->getName());
```

How can i solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered in the [W3C HTML 4 recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html):

> Checkboxes (and radio buttons) are on/off switches that may be toggled
>   by the user. A switch is "on" when the control element's checked
>   attribute is set. When a form is submitted, only "on" checkbox
>   controls can become successful.

And if you are using symfony form component - please [use it properly](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions).

```
$form->handleRequest($form);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $data = $form->getData();
}
```